# Retrieve the corresponding row to an attribute in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to return the values of "ID" and "ctn" corresponding to the most recent date in a fairly large dataframe. Below is a small example of the dataframe (df).

```
  ID cnt date
  1  US  2018-02-01
  2  CA  2017-10-01
  3  UK  2018-06-10
  2  UK  2018-08-23
  1  FR  2017-05-01
```

Hence, the output shall look like as follows.

```
  ID cnt  date
  2  UK   2018-08-23
  3  UK   2018-06-10
  1  US   2018-02-01
```

Applying "group_by" method on 'ID' and then "max()" of the date as

```
df.groupby('ID')['date'].max()
```

giving me the most recent date per each 'ID'; however, I'm not sure how to retrieve the corresponding 'ctn' value in 'df'. Thanks!

Comment: df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the dataframe by dates before grouping. The most recent entry will be always the last:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('ID').last()
```